# Работа с json. Локализация

Tags: java

Хочу реализовать систему выбора языкового файла для перевода текста. Получил язык установленный в клиенте у игрока. Они имеют вид, к примеру, ru_RU, en_EN. По дефолту, если язык не найден устанавливается en_EN
Есть два языковых файла ru_RU.json и en_EN.json
Есть такой код для выбора языкового файла

private final String DEFAULT_LANG = "en_EN";

```
public String TranslateText(Player player, String text){
    String lang = player.getLoginChainData().getLanguageCode();
    File file = new File("uocore.provider.lang."+lang+".json");
    if(file.exists()){
        try{
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(file));
            JsonObject jobj = (JsonObject) obj;
            return jobj.get(text).toString();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        try{
            File def_file = new File("uocore.provider.lang."+DEFAULT_LANG+".json");
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(def_file));
            JsonObject jobj = (JsonObject) obj;
            return jobj.get(text).toString();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Языковые файлы имеют формат

{
  "game": "Русский"
}

{
  "game": "English"
}

Я знаю, что работать это не будет. Помогите, пожалуйста, с реализацией. Как открывать нужный языковой файл для перевода текста игроку?